# Slow Start Threshold in TCP Reno

Tags: networking, tcp

Lets say, the timeout occured at the end of the slow start phase. At that time, the window size will be reduced to half. After that, it goes into congestion avoidance phase instead of going to slow start phase again. In this case, what is the slow start threshold? Is it the end of the slow start or the beginning of the congestion avoidance phase?

Answer (score 3):

For a new connection, receive window size (rwnd) starts with A and the congestion window (cwnd) starts with B.

Sender cannot send bytes more than the minimum of cwnd and rwnd, without ACK. Sender increases cwnd each time sender receives ACK.

At the time the timeout happened, cwnd was X and rwnd was Y. The minimum of cwnd and rwnd is Z.

So, after the timeout, the slow start thershold will be Z/2, or at least 1 segment, and cwnd will be 1 segment.

Check RFC 5681 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Well in TCP-Reno after the Timeout it sets the new window size to 1 and enters the Slow Start! But if you are talking about dupacks after occurrence it halves the window size which is also the new slow start threshold (ssthresh).

Communication Networks - An Optimization, Control and Stochastic Networks Perspective

R. Srikant

Page 29